# sprintf seems to ignore some special characters

Tags: r

Is this a bug?

```
> nchar(sprintf("%-20s", "Sao Paulo"))
[1] 20
> nchar(sprintf("%-20s", "São Paulo"))
[1] 19
```

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.4    fortunes_1.5-2
```

Comment: It works on my machine..`nchar(sprintf("%-20s", "São Paulo"))
[1] 20`

Comment: Ah must be a Mac thing, or a *my Mac* thing then

Comment: Same here, please post your `sessionInfo()`, maybe it is related to locale settings?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with `R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`

Comment: Reproducible on `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)` as well.

Comment: Windows works (surprisingly)

Comment: Thanks I'll submit a bug report

Comment: Yeah, asked for it and not posted myself. Everything okay on: `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`

Comment: @geotheory I'd read through `sprintf` before submitting the bug report as the documentation for `sprintf` makes it clear it is not guaranteed to work the same across OSes.  Got bit by this using a unit test with a `sprintf` based function in a CRAN submission.

Comment: Here's the [bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16807)

Comment: After looking into this a little more I think it really is just platform dependent, which the help file seems to hint at. I'm not 100% positive, but it seems like Linux (and presumably OS X) treat `ã` as 2 characters, while Windows treats it as one. Compare the output of the same C program on [Linux](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/527daf52a6b36012) and on [Windows](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/6fcde62cb187d12eee2e2df0ddbf4c4c#file-sprintf-test-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the help page of sprintf,  it talks about the fact Encodings are important.
If you look at the help page of nchar, you also learn that there are different types.

As a consequence, I see the following  (on Linux, R 3.3.0 beta):

```
> nchars <- function(x) vapply(c("bytes","chars","width"),
                               function(typ) nchar(x, type=typ), 1)
> sp <- "São Paulo"
> Encoding(sp)
[1] "UTF-8"
> nchars(sp)
bytes chars width 
   10     9     9 
> nchars(sprintf("%-20s", sp))
bytes chars width 
   20    19    19 
>
```

So I'm claiming there is no bug at all.
I'm not saying much more than @TheRimalaya  but am drawing a different conclusion

Comment: Useful background. But IMO if a padding feature outputs a string length other than specified it has to be a bug, even if said bug is explained by encoding in documentation.

Comment: A real "solution" would be to provide a patch to the sources so that

Answer (score 3):

```
> nchar(sprintf("%-20s", "Sao Paulo"), type = "bytes")
[1] 20
> nchar(sprintf("%-20s", "São Paulo"), type = "bytes")
[1] 20
```

Comment: I am also using mac, so I could reproduce your problem, when I tried `type = "bytes"` it worked, thats all

Comment: But while `nchar` recognises 20 characters, the string is still only padded to an observable 19.  I guess the short-term hack is to test the difference between the calls and add the difference in space characters.